# Spring Transaction - can't release Transaction after error

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions, transactionmanager

I'm using Spring-tx-4.0.9 in a multithreaded application and have a problem with "stalled" transaction after the thread is killed by OutOfMemory.

Each thread ask `PlatformTransactionManager` (implementation `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager`) to get an transaction via `TransactionTemplate` Propagation is REQUIRED. This template has a timeout set. State of a transaction is managed by application and after all, work is done, then thread calls commit. This returns a transaction back to the `PlatformTransactionManager`, and almost every time releases connection to the DB (in DB, the session for this connection is mostly released)

But if the thread is killed by OutOfMemory, then the underlying transaction is returned to internal transaction pool and another thread can acquire this "broken" transaction. This transaction has the timeout set from the first time and cannot be reset even if new thread call TM to get transaction with `new TransactionTemplate`. So after this timeout expires, every request on transaction throws `TransactionTimedOutException`.

Only available methods on `PlatformTransactionManager` are `getTransaction`, `commit` and `rollback`.
Method `getTransaction` can return new or previous transaction. From returned instance of `TransactionStatus`, I'm able to detect new or stalled transaction, but I'm unable to release it.

Method `rollback` sets flag `isRollbackOnly`, but the transaction is still not released and `getTransaction` returns stalled. If I then call `commit` as recommended by JavaDoc, then nothing changed and the transaction is still hanged.

If I use propagation `REQUIRES_NEW`, then "broken" transaction is suspended, which solve a problem with `TransactionTimedOutException`, but an old transaction is still hanged and holds the connection to the DB (unwanted state).

Is there a way, how to proper release a broken transaction (rollback and release connection)?

**EDIT- Current code for getting a TransactionalStatus**

```
public TransactionStatus beginTransaction() {
    // transaction begin
    logger.debug("Create new transaction.");
    TransactionTemplate template = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    template.setTimeout(txConnectionTimeout);

    TransactionStatus txStatus = transactionManager.getTransaction(template);
    logger.debug(
        "Transaction created. TransactionStatus: isCompleted=" + txStatus.isCompleted() + ", isNewTransaction=" +
        txStatus.isNewTransaction());

    return txStatus;
  }
```

Comment: Why are you managing transactions yourself? If you want that instead of starting/stopping transactions yourself at least use a `TransactionTemplate` instead of this, but the best solution would be to use `@Transactional` to manage your transactions (which has a lot of fallback etc. build in) instead of trying to reinvent all that logic.

Comment: There are many reasons why application manages transaction manually, One for all is that user can specify if all thing he posted to the DB was only for "try" and after work every change is rollbacked. Using annotations is also "no-go". Rework of all logic won't be possible in production environment.

Comment: You have to rework the logic to fix it... So if you cannot rework it how on earth are you going to fix it? Basically every place you are starting/stopping transactions yourself, you have to reimplement the logic as used in the `TransactionTemplate` / `TransactionInterceptor` with proper exception handling etc. \

Comment: Reason why complete rework of transaction logic is not posiblle is simply that there is not time nor money for it. I have to fix a legacy apllication developed by former employee who knows nothing about correct transactional behavior.

Comment: What I don't get is you are using `TransactionTemplate` but still are messing around with the `PlatformTransactionManager` yourself... Why? The `TransactionTemplate` should handle it for you, either use `TransactionTemplate` or not, but you are now have competing mechanisms, which imho is the root of your problem.

Comment: TransactionTemplate doesn't propagate changes in current transaction. 
JavaDoc snipet of getTransaction:
 Return a currently active transaction or create a new one, according to the specified propagation behavior.
Note that parameters like isolation level or timeout will only be applied to new transactions, and thus be ignored when participating in active ones.

Comment: Then you are using it in the wrong way. Post some code because your description isn't making things clearer. As mentioned don't use 2 competing mechanisms as that will complicate things and break things.

Comment: Current code for getting transaction is inserted. BTW: Thank you for your time.

Comment: You aren't really using the `TransactionTemplate` you are using it as a `DefaultTransactionDefinition` (which is what `TransactionTemplate` is extending. I would at least refactor your code to reflect that (and to avoid confusion). Can you show the code for the whole flow (start tx, do stuff, commit/rollback)?

Comment: Whole flow cannot be shown due to complexity of current processes. But every transaction is managed by 3 methods: beginTransaction (method in main text), then commit which calls *transactionManager.commit(txStatus)* and rollback  which calls *transactionManager.rollback(txStatus)*.

Comment: Every DB call is through SimpleJdbcCall and main logic of application is in DB PLSQL, but java has to mantain a main transaction and in success scenario after application sends response and response was accepted, then commit can be executed.

With "try" simulation java will commit partial data durring execution (reports, validation, logs) and rollback the rest.

Comment: If i will have enough time to rewrite the logic, i will use autonomous transaction for different operation and logic of transaction will be maitained by DB, but for now i have no choice to only fix current code.

Comment: For some reason that makes me shudder. I suggest you take a look at the `TransactionTemplate.execute` method, that is more or less what you need to mimic (catching exception and error and rollback that is what I suspect is missing).